# Azure app service deployment error "Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided"

Tags: typescript, azure-web-app-service, vite

I am trying to deploy a webapp to azure app service but getting below errors during deployment.

> client/src/App.tsx(4,20): error TS6142: Module './pages/Routes' was
> resolved to '/tmp/8dc2d5f657b13b8/client/src/pages/Routes.tsx', but
> '--jsx' is not set. client/src/App.tsx(8,5): error TS17004: Cannot use
> JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided. client/src/App.tsx(9,7):
> error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
> client/src/App.tsx(10,9): error TS17004: Cannot use JSX unless the
> '--jsx' flag is provided. client/src/App.tsx(11,9): error TS17004:
> Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
>
> Client: Vite v5.1 Server: Node v18

Locally the app is running without any issue and npm run build also not throwing any error.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

changed tsconfig
changed "jsx": "react-jsx" to "jsx": "react", "jsx": "preserve",

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the correct versions of TypeScript and related dependencies are installed. Verify that files using JSX have the `.tsx` extension. Make sure that the `Routes` component is in a file named `Routes.tsx`.

I tried the sample code with Vite, React, and TypeScript, and successfully deployed it to the Azure web app.

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

**pakage.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.21.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  }
}
```

**App.tsx**:

```json
import Routes from './pages/Routes';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, Azure App Service!</h1>
      <Routes />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**pages/Routes.tsx**:

```json
function Routes() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>This is the routes component.</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Routes;
```

I ran the below command.

`npm run dev`

**Local Output**:

[image]

For deployment purposes, I ran the command below, which generated a dist folder.

`npm run build`.

I deployed the web app using VS Code to azure web app(Linux), as shown below.

[image]

I added this line: `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa` to the Startup Command in the Azure web app, as shown below.

[image]

**Azure Web App Output**:

[image]

Comment: I am able to deploy the client side code to azure without any issue if i remove all the server side node js code from the project folder. I want to deploy both client and server (express) to a single app service plan.

Comment: @Bijoykrishna Das I will try from my side and update.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by excluding the client folder from server side tsconfig.json

Here is the tsconfig

```
  {
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "rootDir": "./",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./build/**/*", "./client/**/*"]
}
```